# MySQL 1 Table, 1 Select, Multiple Wheres

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a "Related Products" section below my product.  I can only get this to work if 
I use two separate SELECTS.  I am trying to combine them but can't get it to work.

Same Table in MySQL -

```
<?php
//select items from db
$items = mysql_query 
   ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (myinvno='dg300') 
   OR (action='alive' AND cate='dogs' 
   ORDER BY productNo ASC LIMIT 0, 4)");

or die(mysql_error());
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))
{
?>
```

This part is for the Related Products section:

> OR (action='alive' AND cate='dogs' 
>   ORDER BY productNo ASC LIMIT 0, 4)");

Thank you ~

Comment: You've only posted one SELECT. Also, what exactly is your desired output? How are two products related?

Comment: Once all main product information is provided on page I will have a related products section.  A 1 row grid of 4 "related" products that are in the same category......The products are related by "cate".  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would look like:

```
$items = mysql_query(" 
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (myinvno = 'dg300') OR
      (action = 'alive' AND cate = 'dogs')
ORDER BY productNo ASC
LIMIT 0, 4"
                     );
```

You were missing a closing parent after `'dogs'`.

EDIT:

Hmmm . . . I wonder if this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (myinvno = 'dg300')
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE (myinvno <> 'dg300') AND
       (action = 'alive' AND cate = 'dogs')
 ORDER BY productNo ASC
 LIMIT 0, 4
);
```

This gets all rows that match the first condition plus four more that match the second.

Comment: Is there another way I should try this while still working with 1 Table?

Comment: I have tried above suggestions plus anything else I could find and STILL the only way I can get it to work is if I open and close 2 queries from the same table on the same product page.  Is it bad to do that?